# Tomar valor de variable en función ajax

Tags: ajax

Muy buenas, lo he solucionado de esta forma:

```
function load_form_T(idTarea){ //FUncion que me rellena el formulario con una tarea que le paso por id

var parametros = {
    "idTarea":idTarea,
    }

     $.ajax ({
            async: false, //Esta es la clave.
            data: parametros,
            url: "/colab_id.php",
            type: "POST",

        success: function(data){
            objJsonT=JSON.parse(data);
            resultado=objJsonT['0'].historias;
        }   
    });

    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es posible, la verdad no se que tan aconsejable es pero se hace con un eval()(), en tu respuesta debes de escribir algo así...

```
            $.ajax({
                "destino.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id': myId                 
                },
                context: document.body
            }).done(function (response) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if (response != null) {

                        eval('funcionCierta')(response);

                    }
                } else {
                    eval('functionFalse')();
            });
            function funcionCierta(response){
                //do some
            }
```

Comment: Muy buenas, gracias por escribir, al igual que con el compañero, he intentado tu metodo  pero he tenido que hacer algo mal. En la función  funcionCierta, hago un return de response y despues desde la pagina hago algo como variable prueba=funcionCierta(); Pero no recibo nada. Esto estaria mal?

Comment: Supongamos que el código ajax lo tenemos dentro de una función por ejemplo: function obtenerJSON(){ //codigo ajax } pero dentro de la función funcionCierta() se invoca a la función obtenerJSON() como haria para obtener el valor devuelto por la función obtenerJSON()??